# AWS OpenSearch package - find out original S3 path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, opensearch

I'm trying to find out how to see original s3 path of the OpeanSearch package that was uploaded and associated several years ago.

I looked everywhere in console and also used `aws opensearch describe-packages` but I can't find a way to map current package to it's original s3 path.

Any help appreciated.